# GUI does not load after updating to Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS from Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 22.04

[image]

I am having this window after updating Ubuntu 22.04.2 from Ubuntu 18.04 (via 20.04). Help me get out of this window and and get beck to regular window.

thanks

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perform all updates, and reinstall the ubuntu-desktop package.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Finally, restart the computer.